# Can't eject my CD from drive

Tags: windows, cd-drive

After Windows 10 installation I can't eject my CD drive. it shows an error message. but i know that there's nothing wrong with my CD format. how can i solve this problem?

Error message is shown below.

*Make sure that disc uses a format that Windows recognizes. If the disc is unformatted, you need to format it before using it.*

Comment: Are you familiar with how to manually eject a CD?

Comment: no. i have tried my CPU buttons.. nothing happens.

Comment: It would certainly help to have the make and model of your computer. If the drive is not ejecting it’s probably because the disc is stuck. Look for a small pin hole in or near the drive tray and push a paper clip in to it to pop the tray open.

Comment: i have successfully ejected my DVD

Answer (score 1):

I assume this issue is occurring after Windows has finished installing.  Even if it is not, and it is asking you to eject the CD, the following should be safe.  Shut down the computer.  Possibly during the shutdown process, but definitely during the boot up process, you should be able to eject the CD.  Just tap the eject button on the drive every few seconds till it ejects.

Once you have successfully ejected the disc, you can try reinserting it if you need, or want to.  You can test other discs, to see if the problem is persistent.